# Github Actions: Push nuget xamarin.forms package

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, nuget-package, github-package-registry, multitargeting

I'm trying to configure a GitHub action that builds my multi-target Xamarin.Forms plugin and pushes the package to GitHub and NuGet. Pushing the package to GitHub and NuGet [shouldn't be much of a problem anymore](https://github.community/t/github-actions-automatically-push-nuget-package/128242). I'm having trouble with building my multi-targeted nuget package on the GitHub CI.

First I had the following GitHub action:

```
name: .NET Core

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.5.0
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.301
        # Authenticates packages to push to GPR
        source-url: https://nuget.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository_owner }}/index.json
      env:
        NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: '%NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN%'
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal
    - name: Pack
      run: dotnet pack --no-build --configuration Release MintPlayer.MVVM/MintPlayer.MVVM.csproj --output .
    - name: PushNuget
      run: dotnet nuget push *.nupkg --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --api-key ${{ secrets.PUBLISH_TO_NUGET_ORG }} --skip-duplicate
    - name: PushGithub
      #run: dotnet nuget push *.nupkg --source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository_owner }}/index.json --api-key ${{ github.token }} --no-symbols --skip-duplicate
      run: dotnet nuget push *.nupkg --no-symbols --skip-duplicate
      env:
        NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
```

and also the following nuget.config in my solution root, to let the action know about the nuget source to download the required NuGet packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

When pushing this configuration to my GitHub repository, I'm getting the following errors at the **Build** stage:

```
/Users/runner/work/MintPlayer.MVVM/MintPlayer.MVVM/Demo/MintPlayer.MVVM.Demo/MintPlayer.MVVM.Demo.UWP/MintPlayer.MVVM.Demo.UWP.csproj(175,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dncs/3.1.301/x64/sdk/3.1.301/Microsoft/WindowsXaml/v16.0/Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dncs/3.1.301/x64/sdk/3.1.301//Microsoft/WindowsXaml/v16.0/Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
/Users/runner/work/MintPlayer.MVVM/MintPlayer.MVVM/Demo/MintPlayer.MVVM.Demo/MintPlayer.MVVM.Demo.iOS/MintPlayer.MVVM.Demo.iOS.csproj(140,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dncs/3.1.301/x64/sdk/3.1.301/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dncs/3.1.301/x64/sdk/3.1.301//Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
/Users/runner/work/MintPlayer.MVVM/MintPlayer.MVVM/Demo/MintPlayer.MVVM.Demo/MintPlayer.MVVM.Demo.Android/MintPlayer.MVVM.Demo.Android.csproj(101,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dncs/3.1.301/x64/sdk/3.1.301/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dncs/3.1.301/x64/sdk/3.1.301//Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

I then modified my workflow to use msbuild instead (at least until the build stage:

```
name: .NET Core

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.5.0
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.301
        # Authenticates packages to push to GPR
        source-url: https://nuget.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository_owner }}/index.json
      env:
        NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: '%NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN%'
    - name: Install dependencies
      #run: dotnet restore
      #env:
      #  NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
      run: msbuild /t:restore
    - name: Build
      #run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
      run: msbuild Library/MintPlayer.MVVM/MintPlayer.MVVM.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:RestorePackages=false
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal
    - name: Pack
      run: dotnet pack --no-build --configuration Release MintPlayer.MVVM/MintPlayer.MVVM.csproj --output .
    - name: PushNuget
      run: dotnet nuget push *.nupkg --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --api-key ${{ secrets.PUBLISH_TO_NUGET_ORG }} --skip-duplicate
    - name: PushGithub
      #run: dotnet nuget push *.nupkg --source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository_owner }}/index.json --api-key ${{ github.token }} --no-symbols --skip-duplicate
      run: dotnet nuget push *.nupkg --no-symbols --skip-duplicate
      env:
        NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
```

But it's still not working.

The console in Github actions prints the following error between the tons of text:

```
/Users/runner/.nuget/packages/msbuild.sdk.extras/2.1.2/Build/LanguageTargets/CheckMissing.targets(44,5): error : The specified language targets for uap10.0.16299 is missing. Ensure correct tooling is installed for 'uap'. Missing: '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/WindowsXaml/v16.0/Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets' [/Users/runner/work/MintPlayer.MVVM/MintPlayer.MVVM/Library/MintPlayer.MVVM/MintPlayer.MVVM.csproj]
```

So this probably means that the UWP tools aren't available on macos. From the output I can see that the android build succeeds, the iOS build succeeds, but the UWP build fails with the former message.

How can I build a Xamarin.Forms package in GitHub CI and push it to my nuget sources?

**Edit:**

Alright, I modified my workflow to use `Windows and MSBuild` instead of `macos and dotnet`, and this brings me a lot closer.

```
name: .NET Core

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.5.0
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.301
        # Authenticates packages to push to GPR
        source-url: https://nuget.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository_owner }}/index.json
      env:
        NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: '%NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN%'
    
    # Add  MsBuild to the PATH: https://github.com/microsoft/setup-msbuild
    - name: Setup MSBuild.exe
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.1
    
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: msbuild /t:restore
      env:
        NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
    
    - name: Build
      run: msbuild Library/MintPlayer.MVVM/MintPlayer.MVVM.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:RestorePackages=false /p:OutputPath=../..
    
    - name: PushNuget
      run: dotnet nuget push *.nupkg --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --api-key ${{ secrets.PUBLISH_TO_NUGET_ORG }} --skip-duplicate
    - name: PushGithub
      run: dotnet nuget push *.nupkg --no-symbols --skip-duplicate
      env:
        NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
```

This action successfully pushes my nuget package to both Nuget and Github, but when I install this package in a Xamarin.Forms project, I'm only getting the UWP classes available in all of the projects, whilst these should only be available in the UWP-targetting project.

Unlike when I right-click my multi-targetting project and click the **Pack** command, the package does in fact work fine. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final workflow:

```
name: .NET Core

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.7.2
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.301
        # Authenticates packages to push to GPR
        source-url: https://nuget.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository_owner }}/index.json
      env:
        NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: '%NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN%'
    
    - name: Setup MSBuild
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2
    
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: msbuild /t:Restore
      env:
        NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
    
    - name: Build
      run: |
        msbuild /t:Pack /p:Configuration=Debug Library/MintPlayer.MVVM/MintPlayer.MVVM.csproj
        dotnet pack Library\MintPlayer.MVVM.BaseModel\MintPlayer.MVVM.BaseModel.csproj --configuration=Release
    
    - name: PushNuget
      run: dotnet nuget push "**/*.nupkg" --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --api-key ${{ secrets.PUBLISH_TO_NUGET_ORG }} --skip-duplicate
    
    - name: PushGithub
      run: nuget.exe push "**/*.nupkg" -NoSymbols -SkipDuplicate
      env:
        NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
```